# oracle get the greatest value of a number varray

Tags: oracle

Is there a function that gets the greatest value of a varray..
actually I have been doing in this way..

```
  DECLARE
        l_max NUMBER;

        type type_value is varray(5) of number;
        arr_value type_value := type_value (0,0,0,0,0);

    BEGIN
        SELECT MAX(field) INTO arr_value (1) FROM table1;
        SELECT MAX(field) INTO arr_value (2) FROM table2;
        arr_value(3) := 63; --fixed values
        SELECT MAX(field) INTO arr_value (4) FROM table3;
        arr_value (5) := 53;  --fixed values

        l_max:= arr_value(1);

        for i in 1..arr_value .count
        loop
            if l_max< arr_value (i) 
            then
                l_max := arr_value (i);
            end if;
        end loop;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_max);
```

Is there something like GREATEST(varray) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do better than this with a **locally declared** `varray` type.

However if your `varray` type were declared:

- in the database (`create type`), or
- in a package specification

then you could use a select statement:

```
declare
  arr_value type_value := type_value (0,43,1,7,3);
  -- Alternatively:
  --   arr_value type_value := my_package.type_value (0,43,1,7,3);
begin
  select max(column_value)
    into l_max
    from table(arr_value);
  dbms_output.put_line('max is '||l_max);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, at least now i have 2 ways ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is very valid, there is no built-in function to return the max value within a `VARRAY` and even if there was one, it probably would run the exact same code ;)